# Filter Change Notifications in Active Directory: Create, Delete, Undelete

Tags: c#, .net, events, active-directory

I am currently using the [Change Notifications in Active Directory Domain Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in .NET as described [in this blog](http://dunnry.com/blog/ImplementingChangeNotificationsInNET.aspx). This will return *all* events that happen on an selected object (or in the subtree of that object). I now want to filter the list of events for creation and deletion (and maybe undeletion) events.

I would like to tell the ChangeNotifier class to only observe create-/delete-/undelete-events. The other solution is to receive all events and filter them on my side. I know that in case of the deletion of an object, the atribute list that is returned will contain the attribute `isDeleted` with the value `True`. But is there a way to see if the event represents the creation of an object? In my tests the value for `usnchanged` is always `usncreated+1` in case of userobjects and both are equal for OUs, but can this be assured in high-frequency ADs? It is also possible to compare the changed and modified timestamp. And how can I tell if an object has been undeleted?

Just for the record, here is the main part of the code [from the blog](http://dunnry.com/blog/ImplementingChangeNotificationsInNET.aspx):

```
public class ChangeNotifier : IDisposable
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (LdapConnection connect = CreateConnection("localhost"))
        {
            using (ChangeNotifier notifier = new ChangeNotifier(connect))
            {
                //register some objects for notifications (limit 5)
                notifier.Register("dc=dunnry,dc=net", SearchScope.OneLevel);
                notifier.Register("cn=testuser1,ou=users,dc=dunnry,dc=net", SearchScope.Base);

                notifier.ObjectChanged += new EventHandler<ObjectChangedEventArgs>(notifier_ObjectChanged);

                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for changes...");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
        }
    }

    static void notifier_ObjectChanged(object sender, ObjectChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Result.DistinguishedName);
        foreach (string attrib in e.Result.Attributes.AttributeNames)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.Result.Attributes[attrib].GetValues(typeof(string)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}: {1}", attrib, item);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("====================");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    LdapConnection _connection;
    HashSet<IAsyncResult> _results = new HashSet<IAsyncResult>();

    public ChangeNotifier(LdapConnection connection)
    {
        _connection = connection;
        _connection.AutoBind = true;
    }

    public void Register(string dn, SearchScope scope)
    {
        SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest(
            dn, //root the search here
            "(objectClass=*)", //very inclusive
            scope, //any scope works
            null //we are interested in all attributes
            );



        //register our search
        request.Controls.Add(new DirectoryNotificationControl());

        //we will send this async and register our callback
        //note how we would like to have partial results

        IAsyncResult result = _connection.BeginSendRequest(
            request,
            TimeSpan.FromDays(1), //set timeout to a day...
            PartialResultProcessing.ReturnPartialResultsAndNotifyCallback,
            Notify,
            request
            );

        //store the hash for disposal later
        _results.Add(result);
    }


    private void Notify(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        //since our search is long running, we don't want to use EndSendRequest
        PartialResultsCollection prc = _connection.GetPartialResults(result);
        foreach (SearchResultEntry entry in prc)
        {
            OnObjectChanged(new ObjectChangedEventArgs(entry));
        }
    }



    private void OnObjectChanged(ObjectChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (ObjectChanged != null)
        {
            ObjectChanged(this, args);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<ObjectChangedEventArgs> ObjectChanged;

    #region IDisposable Members
    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach (var result in _results)
        {
            //end each async search
            _connection.Abort(result);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}

public class ObjectChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ObjectChangedEventArgs(SearchResultEntry entry)
    {
        Result = entry;
    }

    public SearchResultEntry Result { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I participated in a design review about five years back on a project that started out using AD change notification.  Very similar questions to yours were asked.   I can share what I remember, and don't think things have change much since then.   We ended up switching to DirSync.

It didn't seem possible to get just creates & deletes from AD change notifications.  We found change notification resulted enough events monitoring a large directory that notification processing could bottleneck and fall behind.  This API is not designed for scale, but as I recall the performance/latency were not the primary reason we switched.

Yes, the usn relationship for new objects generally holds, although I think there are multi-dc scenarios where you can get usncreated == usnchanged for a new user, but we didn't test that extensively, because...

The important thing for us was that change notification only gives you reliable object creation detection under the unrealistic assumption that your machine is up 100% of the time!  In production systems there are always some case where you need to reboot and catch up or re-synchronize, and we switched to DirSync because it has a robust way to handle those scenarios.

In our case it could block email to a new user for an indeterminate time if an object create were missed.   That obviously wouldn't be good, we needed to be sure.   For AD change notifications, getting that resync right that would have some more work and hard to test.  But for DirSync, its more natural, and there's a fast-path resume mechanism that usually avoids resync.   For safety I think we triggered a full re-synchronize every day.

DirSync is not as real-time as change notification, but its possible to get ~30-second average latency by issuing the DirSync query once a minute.